# Simplify ternary operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, ternary, sonarlint-vs

I want to set the variable **notEmpty** to true or false with a ternary operator, but my VSCode sonarlint marks it underlined in blue with the comment: *Simplify this expression*

Code:
`const notEmpty = list.length > 0 ? true : false;`

This actually works, but could be better.

Comment: `const notEmpty = list.length > 0`

Comment: I recommend reading up on [booleans](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp) some more

Comment: Nice @Nick , that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const notEmpty = list.length ? true : false;
```

no need to compare it to 0 as it returns 0 when it's empty which is false, otherwise it's true

Comment: this could even be simplified to `!!list.length` if a boolean is actually needed. But by default. `list.length` is a truthy statement already if it's not 0

Comment: I agree with with the double NOT operator "!!".
So the first ! coerce the value to a boolean and inverse it, then the second ! reverses it to the original boolean equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```js
const notEmpty = Boolean(list.length);
```

Converting the value of `0` to `false`, or `1` to `true`

As mentioned in the comments above this is equivalent to:

```js
const notEmpty = !!list.length;
```